# Google Map losing its long/lat in Bootstrap tabbed interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [ACF's Google Map](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) to load a map on my page. I pretty much copied everything exactly and slightly modifying the map js with more options on it for styling purposes. I had to change mainly this part in order for the map to load:

```
$('a[href="#directions"]').on('shown.bs.tab',function(){
        $('.hotel-map').each(function(){
            // create map
            map = new_map( $(this) );
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
    });
```

Using their doc ready wasn't working, the map would appear as a grey box. The code change above produces a map, however, once I click onto another tab and then back onto the tab that holds the map, the longitude and latitude seems to disappear. It loads a map that is somewhere way off.

Here's the full js [code](https://pastebin.com/JqWUAjYF).

**EDIT**
This is what I updated the code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.hotel-map').each(function(){
            // create map
            map = new_map( $(this) );
        });

    });

    $('a[href="#directions"]').on('shown.bs.tab',function(){
        // popup is shown and map is not visible
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        center_map( map );
    });
```

Comment: Yeah that is the problem with gmaps. The gmaps element must be in view port then only it will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have triggered the map resize call the center_map(map); function (which is in the code you linked) which will center the map to your markers.